# Volume output changes when resumes from blank screen

Tags: pulseaudio, xfce, dock, usb-c

I have a Ubuntu xfce environment, connected to a usb-c dock feeding 2 HDMI monitors

When my screens go blank, after no mouse of keyboard press, and resumes my volume output is change to a different output than what I originally set. Ex: I connect to a Bluetooth speaker, leave my desk for 10 minutes, come back and resume and my volume output is now set to my dock's speaker output instead of Bluetooth.

How can I make it so, that when I resume from blank screen the volume output stays the same.

Thanks.

Comment: You've provided no Xubuntu release details; is this a Xubuntu install? and what release? or you've got something different (*if so what actually are you using*).

Comment: Does your volume output settings get lost when you do CTRL+ALT+F1 to switch to a TTY you are *not* logged in to? (Return to the GUI with CTRL+ALT+F7 or CTRL+ALT+F8) If so, a workaround might be giving your user account some more permissions

Comment: ''amixer set Master 100%''